Can Poetry package .venv into a tar.gz file?
My poetry configuration is as follows. When executing poetry build, the .venv folder cannot be included in the tar.gz package.
include = [
    { path = ".venv", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "docker", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "env", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "logging.conf", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "poetry.lock", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "poetry.toml", format = "sdist" },
]

Requirement: Use poetry build to build a tar package with .venv using Poetry at CI/CD, copy the tar package into a Docker container, and start the project using poetry run start.
Environment: Both CI/CD and Kubernetes Docker are using CentOS 7.
Common Practice: After CI/CD Poetry build, copy .venv and related project code and configurations into the Docker container.
Question: CI/CD needs additional configuration. Since Poetry has the package/include functionality, can the above configuration code be placed in pyproject.toml as follows:
include = [
    { path = ".venv", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "docker", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "env", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "logging.conf", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "poetry.lock", format = "sdist" },
    { path = "poetry.toml", format = "sdist" },
]

Since Poetry provides build and run script functionalities, can it offer a standardized packaging and startup process?
In CI/CD

Execute poetry install to install dependencies.
Execute poetry build to package the project source code, configuration, and .venv into dist/app.tar.gz.
Use the Dockerfile command ADD dist/app.tar.gz /app.

In Docker

Use poetry run start to start the project.

Benefits:

Standardizes and simplifies the packaging and deployment process.
Simplifies CI/CD configuration by centralizing related configurations in pyproject.toml.


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

You need to ask one single question. -- I will only answer the question from the title "Can Poetry package .venv into a tar.gz file?" and the answer is no. Poetry or not, you should never have the virtual environment inside the distribution package.

@sinoroc I am not using this package for distribution, but as an application deployed to Docker containers

You might want to try "zipapp"-based solution like "pex" or "shiv".
